# Multithreading in NativeScript does not work

Tags: multithreading, nativescript

When I try using workers (aka multithreading) in my Angular - NativeScript app the compiled worker file is not found during app execution. I've found a similar issue on [GitHub](https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/3581), but the instructions there did not help me.

Running the app results in the following output:

```
Project successfully built.
Installing on device 4865d3ab...
Successfully installed on device with identifier '4865d3ab'.
Refreshing application on device 4865d3ab...
Successfully synced application org.nativescript.app on device 4865d3ab.
JS: Angular is running in the development mode. Call enableProdMode() to enable the production mode.
JS: Warning: Setting the 'itemWidth' property of 'ListViewGridLayout' is not supported by the Android platform.
JS: Warning: Setting the 'itemHeight' property of 'ListViewGridLayout' is not supported by the Android platform.
JS: Warning: Setting the 'itemHeight' property of 'ListViewGridLayout' is not supported by the Android platform.
JS: Scan!
JS: Subnet: 192.168.2
JS: Permission is not granted (Error: com.tns.NativeScriptException: Failed to find module: "307b720bbe3cb7a8458a.worker.js", relative to: app/tns_modules/
JS: com.tns.Module.resolvePathHelper(Module.java:146)
JS: com.tns.Module.resolvePath(Module.java:55)
JS: com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethodNative(Native Method)
JS: com.tns.Runtime.dispatchCallJSMethodNative(Runtime.java:1160)
JS: com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethodImpl(Runtime.java:1040)
JS: com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:1027)
JS: com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:1007)
JS: com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:999)
JS: com.tns.NativeScriptActivity.onRequestPermissionsResult(NativeScriptActivity.java:58)
JS: android.app.Activity.dispatchRequestPermissionsResult(Activity.java:7630)
JS: android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:7480)
JS: android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4489)
JS: android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4538)
JS: android.app.servertransaction.ActivityResultItem.execu...
```

How can I solve this problem?
Many thanks for your help.

**EDIT**

I am importing the worker with:

```
import TestWorker from 'worker-loader!./workers/test.worker.js'
```

The worker itself has the file name `test.worker.ts` and the following content:

```
const context: Worker = self as any;
context.onmessage = msg => {
  setTimeout(() => {
  console.log('Inside TS worker...');
  console.log(msg);
(<any>global).postMessage('TS Worker');
  }, 500);
};
```

What am I doing wrong here? Many thanks for the help. Very nice of you.

Comment: I can confirm workers do work with {N} Angular from my experience. So it may be something with your configuration or code, if you could share what you have in your worker file and how you load it from main application, it may be easier to debug this further.

Comment: I'm bit confused, you have named the file `test.worker.js` on import but below you are referring to `test.worker.ts`. Are you sure you have followed the steps for TypeScript based workers [here](https://github.com/NativeScript/worker-loader#usage-in-typescript-projects). If yes, is it possible for you to share a Sample project where this issue can be reproduced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using the nativescript-worker-loader [plugin](https://github.com/NativeScript/worker-loader#usage-in-typescript-projects) as Manoj suggested, you will need to import the worker with

```
import TestWorker from 'nativescript-worker-loader!./workers/test.worker.js'
```

not with

```
import TestWorker from 'worker-loader!./workers/test.worker.js'
```

You can also use

```
import TestWorker from 'nativescript-worker-loader!./workers/test.worker'
```

that should not make any difference.

Also make sure that you declare the module of the `typings/custom.d.ts` file as described in the nativescript-worker-loader [readme](https://github.com/NativeScript/worker-loader#usage-in-typescript-projects) as `nativescript-worker-loader!*`